# How to replace table tag with comma or semicolon in python list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I post WordPress from a csv python list then need a WordPress table. Now how to remove [] and " with commas in my python list.

```
import csv

html_output = ''
names = []

#This 'my_list.csv' file have bunch line of data list 
with open('my_list.csv', 'r') as data_file:
    csv_data = csv.DictReader(data_file)
    #Ingredients is header name
    for line in csv_data:
        if line['Ingredients'] == 'No Reward':
            break
        names.append(f"{line['Ingredients']}")


html_output += '\n<!-- wp:list -->'

for name in names:
    html_output += f'\n\t <ul> <li>{name}</li> </ul>'

html_output += '\n<!-- /wp:list -->'

print(html_output)
```

When I post this python list in WordPress it gets an error and does not replace it appropriately in the HTML table.

[image: This photo photo contain error,and how to fix it]

Comment: what's your input file to reproduce the output and what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the CSV column into a Python list. Then you can format the list as you like.

```
import ast

with open('my_list.csv', 'r') as data_file:
    csv_data = csv.DictReader(data_file)
    #Ingredients is header name
    for line in csv_data:
        if line['Ingredients'] == 'No Reward':
            break
        ingredients = ast.literal_eval(line['Ingredients'])
        names.append(', '.join(ingredients))
```

Comment: when running your code then it throws error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Sorry. I've fixed the typo.